# updating javac version to same as java version

Tags: java, centos

How to use the same version of java 1.7 for both java and javac, on my centos I am getting results like this...

for command java -version:

```
java version "1.7.0_03"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_03-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 22.1-b02, mixed mode)
```

for command javac -version:

```
javac 1.6.0_24
```

how to use 1.7 for javac too? If I need to update JAVA_HOME variable how can I update it? (using what command)

Comment: You can uninstall the Java versions installed and go for the `JDK 1.7`. The `java` file is also part of the `JDK`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have just installed a 1.6 JDK and a 1.7 JRE. To keep both at the same level, just install the 1.7 JDK. Try this command:

```
su -c "yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk"
```

Comment: A couple of thoughts here. 1) You might need to install java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel  2) after install, run "sudo update-alternatives --config javac" to get all the 'alternatives' symbolic links fixed up right.  To see which yum packages provide javac, run "yum provides *bin/javac"

Answer (score 1):

You need to update PATH variable to include the bin directory of your correct JDK .

Make sure your PATH has your JDK bin folder before any other JDK/JRE installation by adding it in begining of your PATH.

**Run below from your Korn or bash shell (console):**

```
export JAVA_HOME=jdk-install-dir 

export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

set JAVA_HOME =C:..... the path where your java 7 is present upto the bin location

example

```
SET JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk_1.7.1
SET JAVA=%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java
```