# how to set equal version for both java and javac

Tags: java, windows, javac

My java and java version is not same.
javac version is older then java version.

[image]

**How** to set version for both javac and java as equal ?

**Path variable** is defined as :

> C:\Ruby22-x64\bin;
>
> C:\Program Files\RubyKit;
>
> C:\Users\skhan\AppData\Local\atom\bin;
>
> **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin\;**
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin;
>
> C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.3.3\bin;
>
> C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;
>
> C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;
>
> C:\Program Files\Git\bin;
>
> C:\Users\skhan\AppData\Roaming\npm

**Java_home**

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65

**JAVA**

> %JAVA_HOME%\bin\java

**JRE_HOME**

> C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_65\bin

I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608204/updating-javac-version-to-same-as-java-version) link but did not find any solution.

Comment: Just to be sure, what does _C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin\javac -version_ print ?

Comment: Check what you have in your `C:\Windows\system32` folder. Is there any `javac.exe`?

Comment: @Berger it gives the same 1.8.0_65 version

Comment: @OstapAndrusiv no there is no javac.exe but there is javaws.exe in system32 folder

Comment: @shan could you check echo %path% in command prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran

```
where javac.exe
```

I gave two path.

i ran `echo %path%` it gives alot of lines.

older JDK path was set also in path variable in system variable path section but latest jdk was set in user defined path variable so i removed the older version from system variables.

Answer (score 0):

To know the location of the executable being launched, try :

```
where java.exe
```

And

```
where javac.exe
```

You should see the corresponding path .